# && operator not working as intended

Tags: javascript, function, logical-operators

not sure what my mistake is in using the && operator but the output is incorrect. Here is my code:

```js
function calculateTriangleArea(x, y) {
  return x * y / 2
}

function calculateRectangleArea(x, y) {
  return x * y
}

function calculateCircleArea(x) {

  return Math.PI * x * x
}



if (function calculateRectangleArea(x, y) {
    calculateRectangleArea.name === true &&
      x > 0 && y > 0
  })
  (function calculateRectangleArea(x, y) {
    return [x * y]
  })
else if (function calculateTriangleArea(x, y) {
    calculateTriangleArea.name === true &&
      (x > 0 && y > 0)
  })
  (function calculateTriangleArea(x, y) {
    return [x * y / 2]
  })

else if (function calculateCircleArea(x, y) {
    calculateCircleArea.name === true &&
      x > 0
  })
  (function calculateCircleArea(x, y) {
    return [Math.PI * x * x]
  })
else {
  return undefined
}




console.log(calculateRectangleArea(10, 5)); // should print 50
console.log(calculateRectangleArea(1.5, 2.5)); // should print 3.75
console.log(calculateRectangleArea(10, -5)); // should print undefined

console.log(calculateTriangleArea(10, 5)); // should print 25
console.log(calculateTriangleArea(3, 2.5)); // should print 3.75
console.log(calculateTriangleArea(10, -5)); // should print undefined

console.log(calculateCircleArea(10)); // should print 314.159...
console.log(calculateCircleArea(3.5)); // should print 38.484...
console.log(calculateCircleArea(-1)); // should print undefined
```

I am trying to get my functions to return undefined if variables X or Y is a negative integer. Right now it is just outputting the integer.

Comment: If `Right now it is just outputting the integer.` is true, then you posted the wrong code here. The code you posted here does not run at all, because it has syntax errors.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your code is supposed to do. I've put your code in a Stack Snippet. If you click the Run code snippet, you'll start seeing syntax errors in the console.

Comment: Really unclear whey you have `function` inside you if statements and what is `calculateRectangleArea.name`?

Comment: [A function does indeed have a `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), but it is typed as a string, so comparing it using `=== true` is likely not to be fruitful.

Comment: Thanks guys My code was needlessly complicated because i do not completely understand how Javascript's logic in interpreting my code. I must have made an error in copying the code because it runs fines on my side. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Currently, your syntax is `if (...)(...)` where both `...` are function definitions. A) You should probably not be defining functions in either of these places in your case, merely calling them. B) The syntax itself is wrong, the latter "block" should use curly braces, not parentheses: `if (true) {//do a thing}`. In addition, note that JavaScript can fail silently, i.e. even if there are errors, it might not come screaming at you, resulting in you thinking your code works when it doesn't.

Comment: I realized its because I was using the function keyword to both declare and call my desired function plus my confusion with correct syntax. Clearly i don't understand how syntax and functions work so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your requirement, that you want your function(s) to return undefined if x or y is negative, I would define the functions as follows:

```js
function calculateTriangleArea(x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0) { //Check if x is < 0 or y is < 0
    return undefined; //Return undefined if that is true.
  }
  return x * y / 2; //Else calculate the output and return it
}

function calculateRectangleArea(x, y) {
  if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return x * y;
}

function calculateCircleArea(x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    return undefined;
  }

  return Math.PI * x * x;
}

console.log(calculateRectangleArea(10, 5)); // should print 50
console.log(calculateRectangleArea(1.5, 2.5)); // should print 3.75
console.log(calculateRectangleArea(10, -5)); // should print undefined

console.log(calculateTriangleArea(10, 5)); // should print 25
console.log(calculateTriangleArea(3, 2.5)); // should print 3.75
console.log(calculateTriangleArea(10, -5)); // should print undefined

console.log(calculateCircleArea(10)); // should print 314.159...
console.log(calculateCircleArea(3.5)); // should print 38.484...
console.log(calculateCircleArea(-1)); // should print undefined
```

Answer (score -1):

In your lines that look like :

```
if (function calculateRectangleArea(x, y){
```

you are *declaring* a function.

To give an example, this is what you are doing:

```js
function foo(x) {
  return x%2 ===0; // x is an even number; 
}

if (function foo(2)) {
  console.log("we got here"); 
}
```

I just get a syntax error.

Your code will likely work better if your remove the `function` keyword, ie:

```
if (calculateRectangleArea(x, y){
```

Comment: Much more needs to be done than merely removing the keyword. At the moment he is doing `if (...) (...)` where both `...` are function definitions.